# How can I add a dot after a bold word in a manual?

Tags: man, documentation

What is the proper syntax for adding a dot that is not bold after a word in bold?

I need to write the following sentense **without the dot in bold**

> **word_in_bold**. Other sentence

But

```
.B word_in_bold
. Other sentence
```

does not generate "Other sentence".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use macros which alternate font styles:

```
.BR bold .
```

will produce

> **bold**.

There are other variants, `.BI`, `.IR`... [`man(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/man.7.html) has the details.

Answer (score 2):

Typically for `mdoc(7)` macros one places the punctuation after the term

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit
.B amet ,
consectetur adipiscing
.B elit ,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
.B aliqua .
```

(Though, not all macros may support this.) To avoid the spaces or otherwise random vanishing of the successive punctuation, a quick review of existing usages

```
find /usr/src -name "*.1" -exec fgrep ".B " {} + 2>/dev/null
```

on OpenBSD revealed `\c` and of course one cannot put `.` alone at the beginning of a line:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit
.B amet\c
, consectetur adipiscing
.B elit\c
, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
.B aliqua\c
\&.
```

Comment: I don't want the dot to be bold.  Any idea?